# at wordpress dashboard cleicking at view site is throwing directory structure

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new to wordpress. I have installed wordpress successfully but when I am trying to do view sites than it is leading me to wordpress directory structure even though I have hello word post.

This click is generating below get request --

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2013:17:32:58 +0530] "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1272 "http://gpwp/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
```

I am not getting any error at apache_error log.My .htaccess file is blank.

Please help me to resolve this. 
Thanks

Comment: If you go to `http://gpwp/wordpress/` manually what shows up? It sounds like you don't have an index file (index.php) or your webserver is not configured correctly to see `index.php` as your index file. Although if you're using the admin panel it sounds like its all configured fine. You might just need to copy over index.php.

Comment: Why your `htaccess` is blank ? revert it to default one.

Comment: Thanks Thomas and Rikesh-- I have changed the .htaccess at wordpress dirctory by adding line "DirectoryIndex index.php" . And it resolved.It resolved.